# Parameters of the waitpid()

Tags: c, fork, pid, waitpid

```
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<sys/types.h>   
#include<unistd.h>  

int main() 
{
    int status; 
    int pid = fork();assigned to variable "pid"

    if(pid == 0)    
    {
        printf("I am the child with pid = %d\n", getpid()); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I am the parent with pid = %d\n", getpid()); 
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0); // line 51
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In line number 51, please clarify the "pid" parameter. what will this process wait for?

Comment: For copying homework verbatim here: -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fork` returns `0` for the child process, `-1` on error, and something else for the parent process. The `else` begins the part for the parent process, that means `pid` in `waitpid` contains the child's PID.

Citing `man wait`:

> The `waitpid()` system  call  suspends execution of the calling
>   process
>          until a child specified by `pid` argument has changed state.  By default,
>          `waitpid()` waits only for terminated children, but this behavior is mod-
>          ifiable via the `options` argument [...]

In short, `waitpid` waits for the child process to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

If the fork is successful, fork returns 0 to the child, and returns to the parent the (positive) pid of the newly forked child process. In this statement, the parent waits the child's termination.

Answer (score 0):

on success fork will return child id to parent and 0 to child,

`waitpid(pid, &status, 0)`;

1. parameter.. ) pid - particular child ID.
2. parameter.. ) &status - exit status that will send to parent by child
3. parameter.. ) option

0 - option is indicated that
parent will wait till child is terminated.